# Spring Rest filter by suffix/file extension

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

We want to deliver some HTML files as well as other files through a Spring Boot Webapp. We want to split the HTML and non HTML traffic by craeting a REST endpoint just for URIs that end with .html.
We tried something like this without success :(

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{*html}")
public String deliverHtml(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
   return doSomeMagicStuff();
}

@GetMapping(value = "{*filepaths}/{*html}")
public String deliverHtml2(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
   return doSomeMagicStuff();
}
```

Unfortunately the above code and some other variations do not work

Comment: That is what the Spring resource handling is for, the magic stuff should probably go in an interceptor (Or be part of the resource chain, depending on the magic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was not finding an answer to the original question so I used this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "**")
```

To catch all request that were not handeled by a dedicated mapping and then I did the split of HTML and non HTML in plain Java Code...

Answer (score 0):

This code worked fine for me. Notice, that for your purposes you can use just ant-patterns (instead of real regexp).

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("filter-content")
public class FilterController {

    @PostMapping(value = "*.xml")
    public void onlyXml() {
        System.out.println("Xml content");
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "*.html")
    public void onlyHtml() {
        System.out.println("Html content");
    }


    @PostMapping(value = "*")
    public void otherContent() {
        System.out.println("Other content");
    }

}
```

P.S.: Also consider using of POST requests for "delivering" content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately your solution is not working way I need it to be. Requests like `http://localhost:8080/filter-content/test.html` are filtered correctly but when I add a path element then it is not triggered anymore `http://localhost:8080/filter-content/somepath/test.html`